# Need command line tools to extract binaries from dmg file on OSX

Tags: macos, dmg, hfs

I am trying to extract certain files from the following dmg:

https://kakadusoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/KDU802_Demo_Apps_for_MacOS_200113.dmg_.zip

I used to be able to extract older versions ${OLD_BINARY} of this dmg using `HFSExplorer` and the following steps:

1. Extract `HFSExplorer`

```
wget -q http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/catacombae/HFSExplorer/0.23/hfsexplorer-0.23-bin.zip
mkdir hfsexplorer && cmake -E chdir hfsexplorer tar -xzf ../hfsexplorer-0.23-bin.zip
```

2. Extract pkg from dmg

```
./hfsexplorer/bin/unhfs.sh -o ./ -fsroot OLD_BINARY.pkg  OLD_BINARY.dmg
pkgutil --expand OLD_BINARY.pkg ./kdu
cd kdu
cat libkduv7ar.pkg/Payload | gzip -d | cpio -id
cat kduexpand.pkg/Payload | gzip -d | cpio -id
cat kducompress.pkg/Payload | gzip -d | cpio -id
install_name_tool -id ${PWD}/libkdu_v7AR.dylib libkdu_v7AR.dylib 
install_name_tool -change /usr/local/lib/libkdu_v7AR.dylib ${PWD}/libkdu_v7AR.dylib kdu_compress
install_name_tool -change /usr/local/lib/libkdu_v7AR.dylib ${PWD}/libkdu_v7AR.dylib kdu_expand
```

But `HFSExplorer` now fails on this new binary.

So, I am looking for other command line tools to extract the dmg.

Comment: Requests for off site resources are off-topic, but I seem to recall 7-zip can read DMG files https://www.7-zip.org/

Comment: Thanks, 7-zip did the trick! If you add this as an answer, I will mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using `7-zip`.